# Working with JSON in Django. Add data and parse iy in template

Tags: python, json, django

I have a code for adding data to JSON:

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render


for pair in pairs:
    for timeframe in timeframes:
        klines = Kline.objects.filter(timeframe=timeframe, pair=pair, closed = True).order_by('-open_time')[:10]
        list_pair_data = []
        for kline in klines:
            kline_data = []
            kline_data.append(kline.price_open)
            kline_data.append(kline.price_close)
            list_pair_data.append(kline_data)

        pair_data = json.dumps(
            {'pair':pair.title,
            'timeframe':timeframe.title,
            'data': list_pair_data})
        all_data.append(pair_data)

return render(request, 'indicators/indicators_list.html',{'all_data':all_data})
```

And i show it in template:

```
  {% for item in all_data %}
    <p>{{ item }}</p>

  {% endfor %}
```

And what I see in page:

```
{"pair": "BTCUSDT", "timeframe": "1h", "data": [[7654.09, 7660.98], [7619.18, 7654.96], [7636.3, 7620.76], [7627.8, 7636.28], [7714.04, 7628.43], [7666.53, 7715.02], [7815.42, 7666.53], [7901.2, 7815.42], [7906.9, 7901.69], [7880.55, 7907.71]]}

{"pair": "BTCUSDT", "timeframe": "4h", "data": [[7627.8, 7660.98], [7901.2, 7628.43], [7939.96, 7901.69], [7802.95, 7939.6], [7881.19, 7802.31], [7895.35, 7882.22], [7904.48, 7895.17], [7966.44, 7904.87], [7890.62, 7966.45], [7847.92, 7890.49]]}

{"pair": "BTCUSDT", "timeframe": "1d", "data": [[7904.48, 7628.43], [7937.16, 7904.87], [8147.94, 7938.15], [7257.32, 8148.48], [7355.28, 7257.45], [7868.67, 7355.26], [8169.08, 7866.59], [7945.26, 8169.87], [7795.62, 7947.56], [6968.24, 7790.71]]}

{"pair": "BTCUSDT", "timeframe": "15m", "data": [[7637.82, 7649.93], [7655.54, 7638.74], [7661.45, 7657.92], [7627.58, 7660.98], [7633.5, 7627.65], [7638.67, 7632.93], [7654.09, 7640.39], [7668.52, 7654.96], [7648.13, 7672.28], [7595.65, 7648.11]]}

{"pair": "ETHBTC", "timeframe": "1h", "data": [[0.031903, 0.031785], [0.03195, 0.031903], [0.031843, 0.031958], [0.031952, 0.031843], [0.03189, 0.031953], [0.031696, 0.031879], [0.031659, 0.03169], [0.03198, 0.031659], [0.031966, 0.03198], [0.031881, 0.031964]]}

{"pair": "ETHBTC", "timeframe": "4h", "data": [[0.031952, 0.031785], [0.03198, 0.031953], [0.032143, 0.03198], [0.032282, 0.032142], [0.032429, 0.032288], [0.03228, 0.032433], [0.032047, 0.032283], [0.03205, 0.03206], [0.031724, 0.03205], [0.031801, 0.031722]]}
```

But how can I get it in format:

```
BTCUSDT - 1h - [7654.09, 7660.98], [7619.18, 7654.96], [7636.3, 7620.76], [7627.8, 7636.28], [7714.04, 7628.43], [7666.53, 7715.02], [7815.42, 7666.53], [7901.2, 7815.42], [7906.9, 7901.69], [7880.55, 7907.71]

BTCUSDT - 1d - [7654.09, 7660.98], [7619.18, 7654.96], [7636.3, 7620.76], [7627.8, 7636.28], [7714.04, 7628.43], [7666.53, 7715.02], [7815.42, 7666.53], [7901.2, 7815.42], [7906.9, 7901.69], [7880.55, 7907.71]

.....
```

In best solution? I need:

```
BTCUSDT:

1h - [7654.09, 7660.98], [7619.18, 7654.96], [7636.3, 7620.76], [7627.8, 7636.28], [7714.04, 7628.43], [7666.53, 7715.02], [7815.42, 7666.53], [7901.2, 7815.42], [7906.9, 7901.69], [7880.55, 7907.71]

1d - [7654.09, 7660.98], [7619.18, 7654.96], [7636.3, 7620.76], [7627.8, 7636.28], [7714.04, 7628.43], [7666.53, 7715.02], [7815.42, 7666.53], [7901.2, 7815.42], [7906.9, 7901.69], [7880.55, 7907.71]


ETHBTC:

1h - [0.031903, 0.031785], [0.03195, 0.031903], [0.031843, 0.031958], [0.031952, 0.031843], [0.03189, 0.031953], [0.031696, 0.031879], [0.031659, 0.03169], [0.03198, 0.031659], [0.031966, 0.03198], [0.031881, 0.031964]

1d - [0.031903, 0.031785], [0.03195, 0.031903], [0.031843, 0.031958], [0.031952, 0.031843], [0.03189, 0.031953], [0.031696, 0.031879], [0.031659, 0.03169], [0.03198, 0.031659], [0.031966, 0.03198], [0.031881, 0.031964]
```

I don't understand, problem is in how I add data to JSON or how I parse it. Or both of it.

UPD:
I tried to do that:

```
        pair_data = [pair.title,timeframe.title,list_pair_data]
        all_data.append(pair_data)
```

Template:

```
{% for item in all_data %}

    {% for val in item %}
    {{ val}}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>---</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

But in this case i cant get directly Pair title. And, how i think, the main question is how can i put i JSON in template in format:

```
 {pairs:[
  {"pair": "BTCUSDT", "timeframe": "1h", "data": [[7654.09, 7660.98], [7619.18, 7654.96], [7636.3, 7620.76], [7627.8, 7636.28], [7714.04, 7628.43], [7666.53, 7715.02], [7815.42, 7666.53], [7901.2, 7815.42], [7906.9, 7901.69], [7880.55, 7907.71]]}

  {"pair": "BTCUSDT", "timeframe": "4h", "data": [[7627.8, 7660.98], [7901.2, 7628.43], [7939.96, 7901.69], [7802.95, 7939.6], [7881.19, 7802.31], [7895.35, 7882.22], [7904.48, 7895.17], [7966.44, 7904.87], [7890.62, 7966.45], [7847.92, 7890.49]]}

  {"pair": "BTCUSDT", "timeframe": "1d", "data": [[7904.48, 7628.43], [7937.16, 7904.87], [8147.94, 7938.15], [7257.32, 8148.48], [7355.28, 7257.45], [7868.67, 7355.26], [8169.08, 7866.59], [7945.26, 8169.87], [7795.62, 7947.56], [6968.24, 7790.71]]]}}
```

Comment: Have you tried `json.dumps()`?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use JSON at all. Pass the dictionaries as they are, or even better just pass the Kline objects themselves.

Comment: in your template have you tried `<p> {{item.pair}} - {{item.timeframe}} - {{item.data}} </p>` instead of just doing `<p>{{item}}</p>`??

Comment: please let us know the actual purpose of this work. I'm not getting the understanding of `how I add data to JSON`, where do you want to add the data. In the template it's already coming. Do you want to append more data to it or something else. If you can tell use the actual usage it'll be better for us to suggest an appropriate answer.

Comment: >>>in your template have you tried <p> {{item.pair}} - {{item.timeframe}} - {{item.data}} </p> instead of just doing <p>{{item}}</p>??  -  Yes, i tried it, but i cant,t that data.

Comment: >>>please let us know the actual purpose of this work. I'm not getting the understanding of how I add data to JSON, where do you want to add the data. In the template it's already coming.  --  Yes, i geting it by whole JSON string, but how can i get just Pair, Timeframe and Data, only values without paametr name ('pair', 'timeframe', etc)

Comment: And i cant put data in case return render(request, 'indicators/indicators_list.html',json.loads(all_data)), i get error: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'